# Config nginx for react route

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, react-router

I have problems when refresh pages in my react project, for that I'm trying to configure my Nginx, because in my localhost works ok.

I'm new in Nginx and I've tried for more than 2 hours without success.

**Context:**

1. I have 2 projects in React with React route, then I need to configure for both but I'm trying first configure one.
2. My first project is in `/var/www/html/app` and my second project `/var/www/html/dashboard`, both works well, with `http://MY_IP/app` and `http://MY_IP/dashboard`
3. I opened the the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`(I removed a lot of commets):

```js
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian-html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

And only I changed:

- `try_files $uri $uri/ =404; -> try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;`
- `root /var/www/html; -> root /var/www/html/app;`

and After in console: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

**Problem:**

When I made that changes, nothing happens and the page `http://MY_IP/app` is blank.

I tried many variants, but when I refresh `http://MY_IP/app/sale` continue with error and route doesn't work.

what I am doing wrong?, That is the correct file to modify?, any suggestion will be amazing.

**Note:**

- My nginx is in EC2(aws)

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs to [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try using configuration as below :

```
server {
    listen    80;
    listen    default_server:80;
    server_name   default_server;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /app {
        root /home/ec2-user/;
    }
    location /dashboard {
        root /var/www/html/;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but It continues with the error page when I refresh ```http://MY_IP/app/sale``` or ```http://MY_IP/dashboard/products```

Comment: Yes, (404 Not Found - nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)), but when I enter to these routes via buttons(react-route), the page works.

Comment: Check the logs under /var/log/nginx/error.log. There may be something to do with paths. Once you identify the directory your request is trying to access just modify your default configuration and restart nginx.